# Does the encode attachment InfoPath from Kotlin or Java have different signature from C#?

Tags: c#, kotlin, infopath

I have encode the attachment InfoPath following the document from Microsoft [attactment-infopath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/encode-and-decode-attachment-using-visual-c-in-infopath-2010) to Kotlin. The class produces different Strings from the C# code. I think because of the InfoPath signature. I want it the same String from C#.

Here is my class.

```kotlin
class InfoPathAttachmentEncoder(private val fullyQualifiedFileName: String) {

    private var base64EncodedFile = ""

    // Creates an encoder to create an InfoPath attachment string.
    init {
        if (fullyQualifiedFileName == "")
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Must specify file name")

        if (!File(fullyQualifiedFileName).exists())
            throw FileNotFoundException("File does not exist: $fullyQualifiedFileName")
    }

    // Returns a Base64 encoded string.
    fun toBase64String(): String {
        if (base64EncodedFile != "")
            return base64EncodedFile

        // This memory stream will hold the InfoPath file attachment buffer before Base64 encoding.
        val ms = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        // Get the file information.
        val f = File(fullyQualifiedFileName)
        DataInputStream(f.inputStream()).use { br ->
            val fileName = File(fullyQualifiedFileName).name

            val fileNameLength = fileName.length + 1

            val fileNameBytes = fileName.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_16LE)

            DataOutputStream(ms).use { bw ->
                // Write the InfoPath attachment signature.
                bw.write(byteArrayOf(0xC7.toByte(), 0x49.toByte(), 0x46.toByte(), 0x41.toByte()))

                // Write the default header information.
                bw.writeInt(0x14)// size
                bw.writeInt(0x01)// version
                bw.writeInt(0x00)// reserved

                // Write the file size.
                bw.writeInt(f.length().toInt())

                // Write the size of the file name.
                bw.writeInt(fileNameLength)

                // Write the file name (Unicode encoded).
                bw.write(fileNameBytes)

                // Write the file name terminator. This is two nulls in Unicode.
                bw.write(byteArrayOf(0, 0))

                // Iterate through the file reading data and writing it to the outbuffer.
                val data = ByteArray(64 * 1024)

                var bytesRead: Int

                while (br.read(data, 0, data.size).also { bytesRead = it } > 0) {
                    bw.write(data, 0, bytesRead)
                }
            }
        }

        val encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(ms.toByteArray())

        return String(encodedBytes, Charsets.US_ASCII)
    }
}

val i = InfoPathAttachmentEncoder(path)
println(">>>Endcoding {} ${i.toBase64String()}")
```

The result from C#:
**x0lGQRQAAAABAAAAAAAAAB8uAAAdAAAA**QQB0AHQALQAyADAAMgAzAC0AMAA2AC0AMgA4ACAAMQA0AC0AMQAzAC0AMwA1AC4AZABvAGMAeAAAAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA36TSbFoBAAAgBQAAEwAIAltDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWwgogQCKK...

The result from Kotlin:
**x0lGQQAAABQAAAABAAAAAAAALh8AAAAd**QQB0AHQALQAyADAAMgAzAC0AMAA2AC0AMgA4ACAAMQA0AC0AMQAzAC0AMwA1AC4AZABvAGMAeAAAAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA36TSbFoBAAAgBQAAEwAIAltDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWwgogQCKK...

The bolded characters here is the different String.

Comment: What you posted isn't a signature, it's a BASE64 encoding. Why write your own instead of using the built-in [Base64](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.encoding/-base64/) class?

Comment: If I encode attachments through Base64 class those strings will not become attachments in The InfoPath app.

Comment: That's not due to BASE64. The code is injecting extra bytes before the actual file contents. It's those bytes that cause the difference. Perhaps the values are wrong, or the order is wrong. Given that InfoPath only exists inside SharePoint (until 2026), why not use the SharePoint SDK ?

Comment: We don't use SharePoint anyway in project business. So I need to arrange the number of those bytes again and do testing right!!!

Comment: In that case you're supporting a dead application. The final InfoPath version, 2013, was discontinued in 2014 and [went out of mainstream support in 2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/infopath-2013). The InfoPath application was discontinued many years ago, with end of support in 2021. Only [InfoPath Services](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/support-update-for-infopath-forms-services-in-microsoft-365/ba-p/3858190) remains until 2026 but even that is in maintenance mode

Comment: Those code i followed this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/encode-and-decode-attachment-using-visual-c-in-infopath-2010

Comment: Doesn't mean the product isn't dead for 9 years. The link is about InfoPath 2010, not even the last version, 2013. End of support means *end* of support. Microsoft doesn't have to update a 13-year old support document, 2 years after End of Support. It only has to keep it available until End Of Life (2026). As for the Base64 string, *do you have any problems*? Because I tried `Convert.FromBase64String` with both `x0lGQQ4=` and `x0lGQRQ=`, and the resulting bytes are the same

Comment: Is it the same but why it still cannot see the attachment in the InfoPath? I take the encode from C# and I'm able to see those attachments.

Comment: `why it still cannot see` perhaps the rest of the code is broken? Or the link doesn't work for InfoPath 2013? The link you posted is about writing an Infopath extension that's run inside Infopath itself. It warns right from the start this isn't guaranteed to work.  I have no idea how you use *Kotlin* to create an InfoPath document. Whatever you do, you aren't using Visual Studio for Applications to run Kotlin

Comment: Never mind trying to support a long-dead application. Why are you trying to do so with a language that was first released *two years after InfoPath was discontinued?* Even the people that remember what InfoPath was or how it worked won't be able to help

Comment: No, the code is not broken but seems like the encoded string is different. All attachments I encoded it with the C# code in the link above can be seen in the InfoPath accept encode from Kotlin.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for trying to help me here.